# how to expand items of a Column into Table - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have an Table into SingleChildScrollView because it is a screen with long texts and two tables. In one of this thow tables, I need do an TableRow, where the first child of this row is a Column, ans the second is only one Container with text. I tryed do this, but the only way I found has doing a Column. The containers of Column did not get expanded. Since the Table has no size, I cannot use Expanded/Flexibe for expand the containers.

(the texts ans tables is into column that is into SingleChildScrollView)

the code:

```
Table(
              border: TableBorder.all(),
              children: [
                tableRowTitle("DADO PESSOAL COMPARTILHADO", "FINALIDADE"),
                TableRow(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          containerTableColumn("Nome completo"),
                          containerTableColumn("Endereço"),
                          containerTableColumn("CPF"),
                          containerTableColumn("RG"),
                          containerTableColumn("Número de telefone"),
                          containerTableColumn("E-mail"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          "Compartilhamento ... pelo APP.",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ]
                )
              ],
            )

containerTableColumn(String text){
    return TableCell(
      verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color.fromRGBO(217, 226, 243, 1),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
        ),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 14,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

how is the table:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

I only want expand this containers of the Column, but is not possible use Flexibe/Expanded, can somebody hep me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, you could use ListTile: TableCell->Container->**ListTile**

I created a CustomTableCell as stateless widget, here an example:

```
class CustomTableCell extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  const CustomTableCell({super.key, required this.label});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TableCell(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: const Color.fromRGBO(217, 226, 243, 1), border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
        child: ListTile(
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
          title: Text(
            label,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 14,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

now you can use it in column, something like this:

```
 Column(
        children: const [
          CustomTableCell(label: "Nome completo"),
          CustomTableCell(label: "Endereço"),
          CustomTableCell(label: "CPF"),
          CustomTableCell(label: "RG"),
          CustomTableCell(label: "Número de telefone"),
          CustomTableCell(label: "E-mail"),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: This solution found! Tahnk you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this, but this doesn't use ContainerTableColumn widget.

```
   Table(
    children: [
      TableColumn(
        children: [
          TableCell(
            child: Container(
              color: Color.fromRGBO(217, 226, 243, 1),
              child: Text('Nome completo'),
            ),
          ),
          TableCell(
            child: Container(
              color:Color.fromRGBO(217, 226, 243, 1),
              child: Text('Endereço'),
            ),
          ),
         TableCell(
            child: Container(
              color:Color.fromRGBO(217, 226, 243, 1),
              child: Text('CPF'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: I edited my question. I put an image of how I want it to look. I will try to do whats u said

Comment: Ok I see better now, wait a few minute, I'm searching for your answer !

Comment: I tryed and apparently these widget (TableColumn and ContainerTableColumn) dont exists, i dont knou if is from some library, but not found. But anyway, thak you so much,!! I managed to solve this problem :)